# Exceção Encoding.RegisterProvider com Restsharp

Tags: c#, restful, restsharp

Olá!
Estou obtendo um exceções em "mscorlib.dll" ao usar o RestSharp à cada requisição feita à API.

> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll (**"''
>   não é um nome de codificação válido. Para obter informações sobre como
>   definir uma codificação personalizada, consulte a documentação do
>   método Encoding.RegisterProvider."**) Hyperlink: Activate Historical
>   Debugging 8.30s       [19772] Main Thread

Isso é mostrado no "Output" do VisualStudio. Mas nada de anormal ocorre na aplicação. Todos os métodos (get, post, put etc) funcionam perfeitamente.

Segue minha requisição...

```
var restClient = new RestClient($"{Secao.ApiBaseUrl}/login");
        var restRequest = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        restRequest.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        restRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        restRequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        restRequest.AddParameter("Email", Usuario, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
        restRequest.AddParameter("Senha", Senha, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
        var responseLogin = restClient.Execute(restRequest);
```

Não encontrei nada relacionado na internet, exceto a documentação genérica do método cidado que é (na minha opnião) vaga.

Conto com a ajuda da comunidade. Grato!